# tag jq how to combine multiple paths into one object

Tags: json, object, filtering, jq

I have an object that I can filter to several paths I wish to keep.  The paths are of the form:

```
[
  "key1",
  "key2",
  "mykey"
]
[
  "key3",
  "key4",
  "mykey"
]
```

What I want is:

```
{ "key1":{
      "key2": .key2
       },
  "key3":{
      "key4": .key4
       }
}
```

The closest I can get is:

```
{ "key1":{
   "key2": .key2
      }
}
{  "key3":{
      "key4": .key4
}
```

using:

```
(paths(objects)|select(last(.[])=="mykey")) as $path|
getpath([$path[0],$path[1]]) as $getpath|
{($path[0]):{($path[1]):$getpath}}
```

Though I can pipe this output to a jq -s '.' command, I cannot find a way to sum the reconstructions of the paths together within the original set of filters.  It appears that the filters reset at the end of each object. $path appears to hold only one path array at a time, rather than be an array of paths.  This prevents me from iterating over $path in a reduce function.

I have created the following script that works but I am interested in finding how to use the paths() function, as well.  I have not figured out how to make it very useful to me, as yet.

```
(to_entries |
 map(select(.["value"][]?|has("mykey")?))|[.[].key]) as $rooms|
(to_entries |
 map(select(.["value"][]?|has("mykey")?))|[.[].value]) as $roomvals| #allows room paths to be avail

##### creates object containing only those locations and sensors within the locations that include "mykey" objs

reduce
range(0;$rooms|length) as $i ({};
.+{($rooms[$i]): ($roomvals[$i] | to_entries |
map(select(.["value"]|has("mykey")))|{(.[]["key"]):.[]["value"]})})
```

Any assistance on these approaches or the suggestion of alternative approaches is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With guidance from peak's responses I can now better pose and answer my question.

I have expanded the data object that peak used in his example so it better represents the problem I was trying to solve.  Now the data better illustrates that "key2" and "key10" have "mykey" while "key6", "key8", and "key11" do not.  What I was trying to express in my question is that I wanted to retain the full paths of "key2" and "key10" which would include "another" as well as "mykey".  I realized that a small modification to peak's example selection criterion would do that.  I only need to add a filter to the selection to retain the 1st two elements of each path that includes "mykey":

```
def data: 
  { "key1": { "key2": {"mykey": {"a": 123},
                       "another":{"q": "six"} },
              "key6": {"key7": {"d": 997} } },
    "key3": { "key8": {"key9": {"b": 234} },
              "key10": {"mykey": {"d": 997},
                       "another":{"q": "seven"} } },
    "key4": { "key11": {"key5" : {"a": 123} } }
  };

def selection(mykey):

  . as $in 
  | reduce (paths(objects) | select(last(.[])==mykey)|.[0:2]) as $path
      (null; setpath($path; $in|getpath($path)) );

data | selection("mykey")
```

Which returns what I desired:

```
{"key1":{"key2":{"mykey":{"a":123},
                 "another":{"q":"six"}}},
 "key3":{"key6":{"mykey":{"d":997},
                 "another":{"q":"seven"}}}
}
```

You will note the selection now indcludes "|.[0:2]".

Thanks to peak for setting my on the right track.  I have voted for his answer as it helped me better phrase my question and give me the insight to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The output that you have indicated you want is not JSON, and it's unclear to me what the desired output is, but the following seems to come close:

```
reduce inputs as $d (null; setpath( $d[0: ($d|length) - 1]; $d[-1] ) )
```

With your input, and using jq -n, this produces:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "key2": "mykey"
  },
  "key3": {
    "key4": "mykey"
  }
}
```

Hopefully, you'll be able to take it from here.

#### Example:

```
def data: 
  { "key1": { "key2": {"mykey": {"a": 123} } },
    "key3": { "key4": {"mykey": {"b": 234} } },
    "key4": { "key1": {"key2" : {"a": 123} } }
  };

def selection(mykey):
  . as $in
  | reduce (paths(objects) | select(.[-1] == mykey)) as $path
      (null; setpath($path; $in|getpath($path)) );

data | selection("mykey")
```

Invocation: jq -n -c -f example.jq

Output:

```
{"key1":{"key2":{"mykey":{"a":123}}},
 "key3":{"key4":{"mykey":{"b":234}}}}
```

Comment: Being new to JSON I probably did not pick the correct way to illustrate what I want.  The primary objects, "key1 and "key3" have children that, in turn, have a child object of "mykey".  What is not illustrated is that "mykey" is only one of several children of the object "key2" and "key4".  {"key2": .key2} is probably better represented another way, say `{"key2": getpath("key2")}`.  BTW I can't find reference to the "data" keyword you used in the jq manual.  What does it do?

Comment: "data" should here have been "inputs".  Are you trying to produce JSON output?